# How to make a keyPress activate in parent frame with iframe selected

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to make a hotkey — every time I press ";", it will perform the function next() and switches the src of the iframe.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){ if(e.keyCode === 59){next()}}
```

The problem is, it kind of "selects" either the parent or the child iframe, the most recent one you were active on. So if I were to click in the iframe, and hit ";", the code basically doesn't run because it never realized you hit the key. However if you click on anywhere else on the page, the parent will be active, and then when you press the hotkey it would work.

Is there any way to make it so it will detect keypresses within the iframe? I've tested this out on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, they all do the same thing. I don't have access to modify what's inside the iframe.

Yes, I can probably just put an input and hook that up to the function, but that would be no fun.

Comment: This is impossible for security reasons. Events are bound to DOM elements which are members of a document. Every `iframe` has its own document and therefore its own set of event listeners. You cannot listen to events in the `iframe` unless you do it in the `iframe`.

Comment: When you say "don't have access", do you mean that the iframes are on another domain, or they files are on your own server, you just can't modify them for this?

Comment: I mean the iframes are of another domain, which I do not have access to.